# Filtering inductor for power electronic converter design formula

Tags: inductor, power-electronics

I have following power electronic converter [image]

and I need to determine inductance of the filtering chokes. I have deduced following formula $$L=\frac{V_{dc}\cdot(1-d)}{f_s\cdot\Delta i_L}$$ (based on \$v=L\frac{di}{dt}\$), where \$V_{dc}\$ is dc link voltage, \$f_s\$ is switching frequency (=12 kHz), \$\Delta i_L\$ is desired current ripple and \$d\$ is duty ratio (\$0\leq d\leq1\$). My problem is that I would like to use Sinewave Pulse Width Modulation so the duty ratio is changing sinusoidally. I don't know what value to substitute. The solution could be to choose the worst case but I don't know what value of \$d\$ coresponds to the worst case. Can anybody give me an advice how to solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering inductance calculation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263981/filtering-inductance-calculation)

Comment: Why did you delete the original question?  It had some comments that may have been of use in answering your question.

Comment: I used the comments in the new question.

Comment: Still, though, it wasn't necessary to create the new question at all.

Comment: The old question didn't contain all what I have done for resolving the problem.

Comment: That's what editing is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution could be to choose the worst case but I don't know what
>   value of d coresponds to the worst case

You have derived a formula for L and the worst case scenario is when L is maximum. With inductors, a smaller value is usually preferred for technical reasons so, choose a value of d that makes L large.

However, I doubt that your formula is correct because if I choose d to be zero then the value of L isn't infinite as I would expect it to be.

Alternatively go and down load LTSpice (free from LT) and simulate solutions to double check your formulas.

Comment: I have started with this assumption \$v_L=+V_{dc}\$ for \$0\leq t \leq d\cdot T_s\$ and \$v_L=-V_{dc}\$ for \$d\cdot T_s\leq t \leq T_s\$. The inductor current at the end of the first interval is \$i_L(d\cdot T_s=\frac{1}{L}V_{dc}\cdot d\cdot T_s\$. This value of inductor current is initial condition for integration the voltage over the other interval. The inductor current at the of the other interval is \$i_L(T_s)=-\frac{1}{L}V_{dc}\cdot T_s(1-d)+\frac{1}{L}V_{dc}\cdot d\cdot T_s\$.